# Applying v-transition to vue.js(v 1.0.1) router-view

Tags: vue.js

I'm building a single page application, using vue.js and vue-router.. right now the links work, but I want to add transition using v-transition.

but according to the documentation

> What’s more important though, is that non-flow-control directives, non-prop attributes and transitions on the component element will be ignored, because there is no root element to bind them to - [vue.js components](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment_Instance)

```
<router-view class="bounce" v-transition="bounce" transition-mode="out-in"></router-view>
```

so technically the v-transition in the router-view tag will be ignored because it is a Fragment instance..

so any idea where I can put the v-transition to apply transitions on route change?

Comment: Did you figure out this by any chance? I am also curious how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Define at least one route node in your component:

```
<router-view class="bounce">
    <div v-transition="bounce" transition-mode="out-in">
    </div>
</router-view>
```

Vue need one element to insert in the DOM if you want to apply transition, or v-show.